# Backup-spsite failing with Fatal error 7105 occurred at 3:31PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator

Tags: backup

I am using SharePoint server 2019 and we needed to backup and restore a site collection, while am trying to do the backup it always throw's this error " Fatal error 7105 occurred at Jan 19 2024  3:31PM. Note the error and time, and contact your
system administrator."
can any one suggest or recommend why this happens when I tried to do some research there is nothing much helpful.

for backup please find the screenshot of the error [image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about which parameters you are using for the cmdlet?

Comment: Hi Crowley, For backup Backup-SPSite "sitecollectionurl" -Path E:\backups\file.bak and failing with the above screenshot error
for restore Restore-SPSite –Identity "sitecollectionurl" -Path E\backups\file.bak -Force